# Is it possible to disable the HTTP referer header being passed by browsers?

Tags: internet, browser, http, www

Is it possible to force browsers so they don't include the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header?

I'd like that every page visit looks like it's accessed by a manually typed URL in the browser's address bar, not like it's the result of activating a hyperlink (even if this is the case).

Comment: Which browser(s)?

Comment: All browsers or any browser. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable referrers in the various browsers and utilities:

**Chrome**

Invoking Chrome with the parameter of `--no-referrers` will disable sending referrers.

Or you could use the extension of [noref](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkpkjedlegmelkogpgamcaemgbanohip).

**Firefox**

Private browsing will already strip paths in HTTP referrers to the bare website
only, such as
`Referer: https://www.reddit.com/`.

Firefox also  allows very extensive control of referrers via switches in
`about:config`.
Their list is found in [Security/Referrer](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Referrer).

The main switch here is 
[network.http.sendRefererHeader](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader), but much finer control is possible:

> - controls whether or not to send a referrer regardless of origin
> - values:
>
>   - 0 = never send the header
>   - 1 = send the header only when clicking on links and similar elements
>   - 2 = (default) send on all requests (e.g. images, links, etc.)

**Opera**

Can be disabled via menu
*Tools > Preferences > Advanced > Network*, and uncheck
"Send referrer information".

**Spoofing web service**

http://referer.us/

**Standalone filtering proxy** (spoof any header)

[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)

**Spoofing http_referer  when using wget**

`--referer=url`

**Spoofing http_referer when using curl**

`-e, --referer <URL>`

**Spoofing http_referer wth telnet**

```
telnet www.yoursite.com 80 (press return)
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 (press return)
Referer: http://www.hah-hah.com (press return)
(press return again)
```

Reference:
[In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty).

Comment: Great answer thanks. Hence as a programmer, it is not possible to rely on the `referer` header.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the addon Clean Links & DoNotTrack.

You can get Clean Links from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clean-links/) & [DoNotTrack](http://donottrack.us) from here.

DoNotTrack will remove the trackers that are following you. This will also make sites think that you typed the address and not came from a search engine such as Google, or Yahoo. Clean Links will remove the obvious ones that are in the link automatically. This one might not work with all sites, but it's worth a try.

If DoNotTrack does not work for your browser, or if you'd like an alternative, use Disconnect.
If you are using Chrome, you can use Fix URL Links Redirect instead of Clean Links.

Get Disconnect from [here](https://disconnect.me) & Fix URL Links Redirect from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-url-links-redirect/ngcknmhpnonbbekommfpihpddphgiojd?hl=en).

Personally, I use Disconnect what you can choose whatever you want.

Comment: Hey there, you deleted your SO question before I could reply: "Looks like your question could indeed use some help. I'd be happy to upvote your question if you edit your question to be a bit more specific (so instead of that list, you could have a paragraph explaining what it should do; lists tend do 'split up' your question into 4 parts, while it's actually 1 question), and explain what research you've done so far and that you've found nothing." So, you could either undelete your question, or post another one which explains a bit more specifically what your problem is. Good luck!

Comment: @joeytje50 Okay, I will undelete & add more info tomorrow. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Let me know when it's back, so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @joeytje50 Here it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851834/compress-a-file-with-lzma-algorithm-remotely-using-php-or-html-or I've figured most of the part out, now I only have to know how to compress it.